# Convergence of piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I'm trying to figure out how the series $\sum g_k$ where $g_k(x) = 0$ if $x \leq k$ and $g_k(x) = (-1)^k$ if $x>k$ converges (pointwise, uniformly or not at all) but I'm having trouble proving what I think. I think that the series converges pointwise but not uniformly, but I'm having trouble because I'm not sure what the limit that the series converges to is, and where to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the sum starts at $k = 0$. For a hint, note that the series converges to zero when $x \leq 0$, since each term $g_k(x)$ in the series is just zero. For $0 < x \leq 1$, $g_0(x) = (-1)^0 = 1$, and for all $k \geq 1$, $g_k(x) = 0$. So for $0 < x \leq 1$, the sum evaluates to 1. Try to continue this for successive intervals of where $x$ can be.

Comment: So is it some sort of step function that goes from 1 to 0 to -1 to 0 to 1 on intervals of length 1?

Comment: I don't think it will ever hit -1, but instead will go from 0 to 1 to 0 to 1, etc.

Comment: Ok...so then I guess it will pointwise converge because for any x eventually k will be greater than it and then after that point you won't be adding anything to the sum at that x, but how would I show it doesn't uniformly converge?

Comment: The $N$th partial sum will be a step function that agrees with the limit only on $(-\infty, N]$. For $x > N$, the $N$th partial sum will be constant 1 or constant 0 (depending on parity of $N$), so it stays far away from the limit function for all large $x$.